# unknown column in IN/ALL/ANY subquery where clause

Tags: mysql

**Problem:**
I know it's documented in MYSQL DOCUMENTS That in where clause "alias" cannot be used since where clause is not populated yet. But i have to get the data matched from other table values in where clause (IN condition).

I have also read some similar kind of post but this one is quite different & big complex one. I couldn't make it working with my efforts of last 3 days.
It's showing error (excepted as per documentation)

**UNKNOWN COLUMN "Ind_ID" in WHERE CLAUSE**

I have to match similarly for **FA_ID** & **PREFERRED_LOCATION_ID** field

```
Select a.job_id, a.Employer_ID, a.Sub_user_id,  
Date_format(a.creation_on,'%d-%m-%Y') as Created_date, a.Job_type, 
a.Designation, a.Open_Positions, a.Job_Description, a.Min_age,  
a.Max_age, a.min_exp, a.max_exp, a.Hide_Salary,  a.company_name, 
a.About_Company, a.Contact_person_name, a.Contact_No, a.Refresh_type, 
a.Response_type,
(Select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.Education ORDER BY pjedu.Education_ID 
    SEPARATOR ', ') user_education 
    from e_pj_edu pjedu
    INNER JOIN education g ON FIND_IN_SET(g.Edu_ID, pjedu.Education_ID) 
    where a.job_id = pjedu.Job_ID
) as Education_ID,

(Select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT h.FA_description ORDER BY uf.FA_ID 
     SEPARATOR ', ') FA 
     from e_pj_fa uf 
     INNER JOIN functional_area h ON FIND_IN_SET(h.FA_ID, uf.FA_ID) 
     where a.Job_ID = uf.Job_ID
) as FA_ID,

(Select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT i.Industry_description ORDER BY   
    ui.Industry_ID SEPARATOR ', ') Industry_ID 
    from e_pj_industry ui 
    INNER JOIN industry i ON FIND_IN_SET(i.Industry_ID, ui.Industry_ID)
    where a.Job_ID = ui.Job_ID
) as Ind_ID,

(Select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT j.location_name ORDER BY 
    upl.Location_ID SEPARATOR ', ') Location_ID 
    from e_pj_locations upl 
    INNER JOIN locations j ON FIND_IN_SET(j.location_id, upl.Location_ID)
    where a.Job_ID = upl.Job_ID
) as Preferred_Location_ID,

(Select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT uk.Keyword_Name  ORDER BY uk.Keyword_ID 
    SEPARATOR ', ') keyskills 
    from e_pj_keywords uk
    where a.Job_ID = uk.Job_ID
) as Keyword_Name,

GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cc.salary_description ORDER BY cc.salary_ID 
SEPARATOR ', ') Min_salary, 

GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT dd.salary_description ORDER BY dd.salary_ID 
SEPARATOR ', ') Max_salary

from post_jobs a
    INNER JOIN user_salary cc ON FIND_IN_SET(cc.salary_ID, a.Min_salary)  
    INNER JOIN user_salary dd ON FIND_IN_SET(dd.salary_ID, a.Max_salary)
WHERE a.Designation LIKE '%MIS%' or a.company_name LIKE '%MIS%' 
    And a.max_exp <= 9 
    And a.Max_salary<=110 
    And Ind_ID IN (10001,10002,10004)
    And FA_ID IN(1001) 
group by a.job_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing that comes in my mind is just move your aliased where conditions to outer query, i.e.:

```
select * from ( 
   Select a.job_id ....
   WHERE a.Designation LIKE '%MIS%' or a.company_name LIKE '%MIS%' 
      And a.max_exp <= 9 
      And a.Max_salary<=110 
   group by a.job_id
) inner 
where 
Ind_ID IN (10001,10002,10004)
And FA_ID IN(1001)
```

GL!

Comment: Thanks a ton Wawrzyniec :-) you saved my day. That worked. I don't know why this didn't came to my mind. well, i am curious to know, is this really a better way to search or there are some other options using query performance can be improved considering this will be a large database very soon.

Comment: First of all is there a need to use GROUP_CONCAT for Ind_ID and FA_ID ? In where clause there used a scalar values.  You are using also a lot of FIND_IN_SET, can it be replaced by regular join with proper indexing? GL!

Comment: Yes, There is need of Multiple Group_Concat function because in search result i need to display output in comma separated format. Here i am converting numeric values to text format. All this happening for Job portal where you need to display keywords, industries, functional areas in comma separated format. user can search multiple values for multiple fields at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Posting revised query which worked. May be this helps someone from wasting 3 days like me :-)

```
select * from (
            Select a.job_id, a.Employer_ID, a.Sub_user_id, Date_format(a.creation_on,'%d-%m-%Y') as Created_date, a.Job_type, a.Designation, a. 
            Open_Positions, a.Job_Description, a.Min_age, a.Max_age, a.min_exp, a.max_exp, a.Hide_Salary, a.company_name, a.About_Company, a.Contact_person_name, 
            a.Contact_No, a.Refresh_type, a.Response_type,
                (Select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.Education ORDER BY pjedu.Education_ID SEPARATOR ', ') user_education 
                    from e_pj_edu pjedu
                    INNER JOIN education g ON FIND_IN_SET(g.Edu_ID, pjedu.Education_ID) 
                    where a.job_id = pjedu.Job_ID
                ) as Education_ID,
                (Select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT h.FA_description ORDER BY uf.FA_ID SEPARATOR ', ') FA 
                    from e_pj_fa uf 
                    INNER JOIN functional_area h ON FIND_IN_SET(h.FA_ID, uf.FA_ID) 
                    where a.Job_ID = uf.Job_ID
                ) as FA_ID,
                (Select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT i.Industry_description ORDER BY ui.Industry_ID SEPARATOR ', ') Industry_ID 
                    from e_pj_industry ui 
                    INNER JOIN industry i ON FIND_IN_SET(i.Industry_ID, ui.Industry_ID)
                    where a.Job_ID = ui.Job_ID
                ) as Ind_ID,
                (Select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT j.location_name ORDER BY upl.Location_ID SEPARATOR ', ') Location_ID 
                    from e_pj_locations upl 
                    INNER JOIN locations j ON FIND_IN_SET(j.location_id, upl.Location_ID)
                    where a.Job_ID = upl.Job_ID
                ) as Preferred_Location_ID,
                (Select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT uk.Keyword_Name  ORDER BY uk.Keyword_ID SEPARATOR ', ') keyskills 
                        from e_pj_keywords uk
                        where a.Job_ID = uk.Job_ID
                ) as Keyword_Name,
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cc.salary_description ORDER BY cc.salary_ID SEPARATOR ', ') Min_salary, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT dd.salary_description ORDER BY dd.salary_ID SEPARATOR ', ') Max_salary
                from post_jobs a
                INNER JOIN user_salary cc ON FIND_IN_SET(cc.salary_ID, a.Min_salary) 
                INNER JOIN user_salary dd ON FIND_IN_SET(dd.salary_ID, a.Max_salary)
                group by a.Job_id 
        ) aa
WHERE Designation LIKE '%op%' or company_name LIKE '%op%' 
And max_exp <= 15 
And Max_salary<=120 
and Ind_ID IN (10001,10002,10004,10003)
And FA_ID IN(1001,1002,1003)
group by Job_id
```

Comment: This still does not address the concern of @Wawrzyniec .  Is FA_ID 3 possible values?  Or is it supposed to be the GROUP_CONCAT that results in the single string "1001, 1002, 1003", which it does not do.

Comment: Rick, There could be 5-10 possible values under FA_ID & similarly in Industry_ID depending upon user selection. I am doing GROUP_CONCAT to display output string fetched from another table as comma separated on output page using FA_ID, Ind_ID & Keyword_Name.